# C# - ICertView2::OpenConnection Method

Tags: c#

Iam using the OpenConnection from CertAdm.dll to open a connection.

Like this:
             `CERTADMINLib.CCertView connection = new CERTADMINLib.CCertViewClass();`

I was wondering how can I close this connection when Iam done with it? I havent found anything about closing the connection.

Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good practice to use "using" pattern for those kind of connections:

```
  using (CERTADMINLib.CCertView connection = new CERTADMINLib.CCertViewClass())
  {
    // do something ...
  }
```

after the last brace connections are disposed.

Comment: I will try it, thnx very much.

Answer (score 0):

Close the connection so:

```
ICertView2 certView = null;
IEnumCERTVIEWROW row = null;
try
{
    certView = new CCertView();
    certView.OpenConnection( _strCAConfig );
    certView.SetResultColumnCount( 1 );
    certView.SetResultColumn( certView.GetColumnIndex( 0, "RequestID" ) );
    row = certView.OpenView();
    row.Next();
    return row.GetMaxIndex();
}
finally
{
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject( row );
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject( certView );
}
```